# JSON Array to PHP Variable

Tags: php, arrays, json

I use Rockstar's Social Club API for Crews and i try to put the contents into PHP variables.
This is my script:

```
<?php
$crewinfo = json_decode(utf8_encode(file_get_contents('http://socialclub.rockstargames.com/crewsapi/GetCrewDetails?crewId=11395854')), true);

$c_name = $crewinfo->CrewDetails->CrewName;
$c_tag = $crewinfo->CrewDetails->CrewTag;
$c_members = $crewinfo->CrewDetails->MemberCount;
$c_scurl = 'http://socialclub.rockstargames.com' . $crewinfo->CrewDetails->CrewUrl;
$c_motto = $crewinfo->CrewDetails->CrewMotto;
$c_color = $crewinfo->CrewDetails->CrewColour;

?>
```

The Results of the URL gave me:

```
{"CrewDetails":{"MemberId":0,"CrewId":11395854,"CrewName":"THE GREEKS 
360","NameStripped":"the_greeks_360","CrewTag":"GRKS","CrewMotto":"Energo Crew ka8e mera ONLINE!!! 
Dexomaste olous ts nrml 
players!","CrewUrl":"/crew/the_greeks_360","MemberCount":34,"FormattedMemberCount":"34",
"IsPrivate":true,"IsPrimary":true,"RankOrder":1,"CrewType":"chatterBoxes","IsFounderCrew":false,
"FriendCount":0,"IsSystemPrivate":false,"IsOpen":false,"Dev":false,"CrewColour":"#70FF03","Division":"21-50","HasMembers":false,"HasBannedPlayers":false,"HasJoinRequests":false,"CanViewManagePage":false,
"CanEditCrewSettings":false,"CanInvite":false,"CanLeave":false,"ShowActions":false,"CanJoin":false,
"IsLoggedIn":false,"CanRequestInvite":false,"IsJoinRequestPending":false,"ShowMaxExceededBtn":false,
"IsMember":false},"Members":[{"RockstarId":33505889,"MemberId":30172107,"Name":"drantifat","AvatarUrl":"GTAO/gtao09.png"},
{"RockstarId":26352137,"MemberId":30173094,"Name":"GrecoLoco777","AvatarUrl":"GTAVCAnniversary/GTAVC58.png"},
{"RockstarId":35911863,"MemberId":30209163,"Name":"zempili","AvatarUrl":"MaxPayne3/MP3_46.jpg"},
{"RockstarId":47535710,"MemberId":30210870,"Name":"DoNotDisturb21","AvatarUrl":"GTAO/gtao07.png"},
{"RockstarId":39622658,"MemberId":30248665,"Name":"kosthkas","AvatarUrl":"Exclusives/rockstar_downtown_1.png"}],"Status":true}
```

When i call a PHP Variable up to show it on the site i use

```
<?php echo $c_name; ?>
```

But it doesn't shows anything, just blank.
I could really use some help now, Thanks.

Comment: Since you used the second argument to `json_decode()` it returns associative arrays, not objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using

```
json_decode("jsonstring",true);
```

if you provide the second parameter as TRUE, then an associative array will be returned instead of the object you are expecting.

#### working code

```
<?php
$json = '{"CrewDetails":{"MemberId":0,"CrewId":11395854,"CrewName":"THE GREEKS 360"}}';

/** working sample-1 **/
$crewinfo = json_decode($json, false);
var_dump($crewinfo->CrewDetails->CrewName);//string 'THE GREEKS 360' (length=14)

/** working sample-2 **/
$crewinfo = json_decode($json, true);
var_dump($crewinfo['CrewDetails']['CrewName']);//string 'THE GREEKS 360' (length=14)
?>
```

#### update to comments

do it like

```
$json = utf8_encode(file_get_contents('http://socialclub.rockstargames.com/crewsapi/GetCrewDetails?crewId=11395854'));

/** working sample-1 **/
$crewinfo = json_decode($json, false);
var_dump($crewinfo->CrewDetails->CrewName);

/** working sample-2 **/
$crewinfo = json_decode($json, true);
var_dump($crewinfo['CrewDetails']['CrewName']);
```

Comment: the $json does not extracts it from the url, does it? Thanks for your explaining, but i need to extract it for the url.

Comment: just replace the string with your `file_get_contents` function code you alreay have in question and it will work fine. I was just explaining the part where u went wrong.

Answer (score 0):

It's because you are manipulating it has an object, while you decoded it to an array.

This will work :

```
$c_name = $crewinfo['CrewDetails']['CrewName'];
```

Output :

```
THE GREEKS 360
```

Answer (score 0):

First you have to decode your json data:

```
$string='{"name":"John Adams"}';
$json_a=json_decode($string,true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your converting it to an array but you treat it as an object

remove the true parameter from your json_decode and it works fine

```
$crewinfo = json_decode(utf8_encode(file_get_contents('http://socialclub.rockstargames.com/crewsapi/GetCrewDetails?crewId=11395854')));

$c_name = $crewinfo->CrewDetails->CrewName;
$c_tag = $crewinfo->CrewDetails->CrewTag;
$c_members = $crewinfo->CrewDetails->MemberCount;
$c_scurl = 'http://socialclub.rockstargames.com' . $crewinfo->CrewDetails->CrewUrl;
$c_motto = $crewinfo->CrewDetails->CrewMotto;
$c_color = $crewinfo->CrewDetails->CrewColour;
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

Answer (score 0):

You should use foreach loop to print all the key values from the json_decode() array which is below here :

```
   foreach($crewinfo['CrewDetails'] as $key => $value) {
        echo $key.' = '.$value;
    }
```

This $key will show you the index name like CrewName and $value will give its value.

Answer (score 0):

Two issues:

1. the JSON is invalid need to strip out line breaks
2. You are asking json_encode to return an assoc. array whereas you are using the object pointer to access the data.

Strip out the breaks from your json string and remove the `true` parameter so the method returns an object rather than an array:

```
$crewinfo = json_decode(preg_replace('/\s\s+/','',$json));
```

Here is a link to the code working fine for you:

http://codepad.org/jTjiAZdn